# Why are all of my file paths broken with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm starting to use innerHTML quite a lot with Javascript.
I've also just started using Parcel Bundler.

My problem is that all of my href links and img src file paths don't seem to be working while using innerHTML.

I should also mention that the img links already in the html file are working fine. and I'm using ./ for the innerHTML assigned to the same html file so I can't see any file path issues. Furthermore, if I copy and paste the innerHTML from the JS file into the HTML file the images work fine so it absolutely can't be a file path issue.

There is a lot of code so I'd rather not flood this questions with lines upon lines however this is what I believe to be the relevant code:

I'm using grid-template-areas and flexbox. 'main' being one of my template-area's.

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="list-box">
    <div class="nav-panel">
      <a class="nav-div-l nav-pic-bg hover"><img class="nav-pic-l nav-img" src="./img/arrow-left.png" alt="Logout Arrow">
      <h2 id="logout-btn">Logout</h2></a>
      <a id="user-btn" class="nav-div-c hover"><img class="nav-pic-c nav-img" src="./img/user.jpg" alt="User Picture">
      <h2>Username</h2></a>
      <a id="settings-btn" class="nav-div-r hover hide-mobile"><h2>Settings</h2>
      <img class="nav-pic-r nav-img settings-img" src="./img/white-cog-hi.png" alt="Settings Cog"></a>
      <a class="settings-btn hide-desktop"><img class="nav-img" src="./img/white-cog-hi.png" alt="Settings Cog"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="settings"></div>
    <div id="user"></div>
    <div id="lists"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

At the top of this JS file you'll notice a module import. This is simply JS data for the website.

JS:

```
import data from './data.js';

const settingsBtn = document.getElementById('settings-btn'); // nav links
const logoutBtn = document.getElementById('logout-btn');
const userBtn = document.getElementById('user-btn');

const lists = document.getElementById('lists');
const settings = document.getElementById('settings');
const user = document.getElementById('user');

logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {  // change to lists page
  displayLists();
  settingsBtn.style.display = 'flex';
  logoutBtn.innerHTML = 'Logout';
  userBtn.style.display = 'flex';

  settings.innerHTML = '';
  user.innerHTML = '';
});

userBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {  // change to user page
  displayUser();
  settingsBtn.style.display = 'flex';
  logoutBtn.innerHTML = 'Back';
  userBtn.style.display = 'none';

  lists.innerHTML = '';
  settings.innerHTML = '';
});

settingsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {  // change to settings page
  displaySettings();
  settingsBtn.style.display = 'none';
  logoutBtn.innerHTML = 'Back';
  userBtn.style.display = 'flex';

  lists.innerHTML = '';
  user.innerHTML = '';
});

const displayLists = () => {  // lists
  lists.innerHTML += `
  <div class="category-panel hide-mobile">
    <h3>Name:</h3>
    <div class="category-sections">
      <div class="category-l"><h3>Items:</h3></div>
      <div class="category-c"><h3>Reminders:</h3></div>
      <div class="category-r"><h3>Created:</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.lists.length; i++) {
    let obj = eval(data.lists[i]);
    let totalReminders = getTotalReminders(obj);

    lists.innerHTML += `
      <a href="./list.html">
        <div class="list-item">
          <p>${obj.name}</p>
          <div class="category-sections">
            <p class="category-circle-border">${obj.items.length}</p>
            <p class="category-circle-border">${totalReminders}</p>
            <p class="date-width">${obj.created}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    `;
  }
};

const getTotalReminders = passed => {
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < passed.items.length; i++) {
    total += passed.items[i].reminders;
  }

  return total;
};

displayLists();

const displaySettings = () => {
  settings.innerHTML = `
  <div class="row-auto">
    <div class="flex-column hover">
      <img class="api-img" src="./img/apple.png" alt="Apple Logo">
      <div class="flex">
        <h3>Connected</h3>
        <div class="circle api-colour-online"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column hover">
      <img class="api-img" src="./img/windows.png" alt="Windows Logo">
      <div class="flex">
        <h3>Connected</h3>
        <div class="circle api-colour-online"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column hover">
      <img class="api-img" src="./img/android.png" alt="Android Logo">
      <div class="flex">
        <h3>Not Connected</h3>
        <div class="circle api-colour-offline"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column hover">
      <img class="api-img" src="./img/google.png" alt="Google Logo">
      <div class="flex">
        <h3>Connected</h3>
        <div class="circle api-colour-online"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-auto-c">
    <h3>Background:</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="flex settings-bg-contain-padding">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-0.jpg" alt="Background 1">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-1.jpg" alt="Background 2">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-2.jpg" alt="Background 3">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-3.jpg" alt="Background 4">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-4.jpg" alt="Background 5">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="./img/background-5.jpg" alt="Background 6">
    <div class="hover">
      <img class="settings-bg-pic-upload" src="./img/background-0.jpg" alt="Arrow Up">
      <p class="black-text">Upload</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-auto">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <h3>Background On</h3>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-back"></div>
        <div class="slider-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <h3>Random Slider</h3>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-back"></div>
        <div class="slider-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <h3>24h Time</h3>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-back"></div>
        <div class="slider-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `;

  const getBG = document.getElementsByClassName('settings-bg-pic');

  const changeBG = BG => {  // settings background change
    for (let i = 0; i < BG.length; i++) {
      BG[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(./img/background-${[i]}.jpg)`;
      });
    }
  };

  changeBG(getBG);

  const slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

  const sliders = (slide) => {  // sliders
    slide.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('click', (i) => {
      i.currentTarget.querySelector('.slider-circle').classList.toggle('slider-checked');
    }));
  };

  sliders(slide);
}

const displayUser = () => {
  user.innerHTML = ``;
}
```

While running Parcel Bundler if I click on my links it simply reloads the page and all of my img's are broken with the alt showing.

Comment: What does your folder/file structure look like? Your paths are first going up one level 
 (./img/) before looking for the img folder.

Comment: In my src folder are all of my html files with my css folder, my js folder and my img folder.

Comment: I think your paths should look like, for example: img/white-cog-hi.png Leave the ./ off the front of the path

Comment: Nope. The issue isn't with the img src links that are already in the html. Those images are fine. Just to see I took the ./ away from some img src links within the innerHTML but still no luck.

Comment: Heard of the `<template>` or `DocumentFragment` interfaces? In your case - you've got oodles of HTML code hidden away in a javascript string. Reckon I'd be using a template there - you can appendChild with a clone of the template's content, which is both faster than string evaluation and better for the white-space control (amongst other things). Have a look.

Comment: @MichaelvE - he is using `./img/apple.png` which _does not_ go up one level (to the parent directory). `.` represents the _current_ directory so `./img/` is the "img" directory _under_ the current dir, and `..` represents the parent, so if the path was `../img/apple.png` _that_ would go up one level.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. The problem was with Parcel Bundler and how it bundles the img files to the dist folder. It doesn't like simply putting img src file paths in the innerHTML. It wants you to import the img's into the JS its self. Here is my solution:

```
import arrowUp from '../img/arrow-up.png';
import arrowDown from '../img/arrow-down.png';
import arrowLeft from '../img/arrow-left.png';
import arrowRight from '../img/arrow-right.png';

import user from '../img/user.jpg';

import apiApple from '../img/apple.png';
import apiWindows from '../img/windows.png';
import apiAndroid from '../img/android.png';
import apiGoogle from '../img/google.png';

import plus from '../img/add.png';
import tick from '../img/tick-green.png';
import cog from '../img/cog.png';
import bin from '../img/bin.png';
import doc from '../img/document.png';
import lock from '../img/lock.png';
import png from '../img/save.png';

import BG0 from '../img/background-0.jpg';
import BG1 from '../img/background-1.jpg';
import BG2 from '../img/background-2.jpg';
import BG3 from '../img/background-3.jpg';
import BG4 from '../img/background-4.jpg';
import BG5 from '../img/background-5.jpg';

import fb from '../img/facebook.png';
import insta from '../img/insta.png';
import twitter from '../img/twitter.png';

module.exports = {
  arrows: [
    arrowUp, arrowDown, arrowLeft, arrowRight,
  ],

  symbols: [
    plus, tick, cog, bin, doc, lock, png,
  ],

  user: [
    user,
  ],

  bgImg: [
    BG0, BG1, BG2, BG3, BG4, BG5,
  ],

  apiImg: [
    apiApple, apiWindows, apiAndroid, apiGoogle,
  ],

  footer: [
    fb, insta, twitter,
  ],
}
```

Main JS:

```
import img from './images.js';

<div class="flex settings-bg-contain-padding">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[0]}" alt="Background 1">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[1]}" alt="Background 2">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[2]}" alt="Background 3">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[3]}" alt="Background 4">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[4]}" alt="Background 5">
  <img class="settings-bg-pic hover" src="${img.bgImgs[5]}" alt="Background 6">
  <div class="hover">
    <img class="settings-bg-pic-upload" src="${img.bgImgs[0]}" alt="Arrow Up">
    <p class="black-text">Upload</p>
  </div>
</div>
```